# Why does my delay task not trigger the Task.WaitAny()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

So I have the following:

```
if (await Task.WhenAny(myLongRunningTask, Task.Delay(9000)) != myLongRunnnigTask && !myLongRunningTask.IsFaulted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TimedOut");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

Seems to work fine when I complete my task; but if I never complete the long running task then this just hangs instead of timing out after 9 seconds. Even put in the faulted test to be sure.

(NOTE: Real code does more than just commandline write; but it never even gets into the scope; though I did try just commandline writing too... no change.)

Yet doing what looks to me to be exactly the same thing in LinqPad:

```
async void Main()
{
    var Other = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(15000); });
    if(await Task.WhenAny(Other, Task.Delay(4000)) != Other && !Other.IsFaulted) "TimedOut".Dump();
    else "Completed".Dump();

    Other = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); });
    if(await Task.WhenAny(Other, Task.Delay(4000)) != Other && !Other.IsFaulted) "TimedOut".Dump();
    else "Completed".Dump();
}
```

That happily writes TimedOut then Completed.

The first code section is deep down in a pretty huge module. But I can't see what might side-effect it to this odd behaviour... What might I be missing?

**NOTE on accepted answer:**

The question here was what might be side-effecting this. @Douglas' answer indicates the side effect that was impacting my code. That does not necessarily fix the issue; just tells you where your problem lies. However he helpfully added a comment with a link to an article that **does** help you fix it.

Comment: The fact that your complete example using this snippet works as intended means that you've specifically demonstrated that the problem is in some other code.  Without any idea what that code is, it's impossible to say why it isn't working.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yep I agree with both points. The question was directed to what 'could' be contributing. I would agree that it is almost certainly a side effect. But I am at a loss as to what I should try to isolate further. If I could make the complete and verifiable example I would hope I would be well on the way to solving the issue.

Comment: `to what 'could' be contributing` That is too broad a question. There is no point asking what could contribute (although my answer below is the most likely cause) - if you show us the code we can work out what **is** the cause.

Comment: Though I totally get your point on this being too broad; it was something I had spent an age trying to isolate. This post was desperation and thankfully it worked as Douglas's answer solved my issue. That said I still +1 on yours @mjwills as I do need to revisit other usecases to make sure. So thanks all.

Comment: Minor clarification on your note: Adding the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does fix the issue. Replacing `.Wait()` and `.Result` calls by `async`–`await` all the way also fixes the issue. Either one is sufficient in isolation, although avoiding blocking calls is indeed more important.

Comment: @Douglas Adding `ConfigureAwait` hides the issue and results in the bug potentially manifesting in slightly different ways, if it even does anything at all (it very likely won't).  It doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @Servy: That's incorrect. Applying `ConfigureAwait(false)` throughout the code that is blocked will prevent the deadlock. You can read Stephen Cleary's article from my link: "It is best to apply both best practices. Either one will prevent the deadlock, but both must be applied to achieve maximum performance and responsiveness."

Comment: @Douglas If you can prevent any code, *anywhere* from accessing the synchronization context in any way, then you won't have a deadlock.  Of course, if any of that code *needed* the synchronization context, then it's just broken in a different way.  And there are lots of ways of scheduling code to use the synchronization context beyond just awaiting without `ConfigureAwait(false)`, if any of those methods are used *anywhere* in the operation being synchronously waited on, you still have a deadlock.  So *best case*, you get a different error stemming from the same problem.

Comment: ...which clearly wasn't the case in the OP's scenario, since adding the `ConfigureAwait(false)` eliminated the deadlock. But this is devolving into another pointless discussion. I've already stated that eliminating the blocking calls is more important, and linked to Cleary's article which explains the technicalities better than I could. I have nothing further to add.

Comment: Sorry to have put cats amongst pigeons... the ConfigureAwait(false) showed me what the problem was. In my case it didn't solve it; but reading the article you linked to @Douglas did. I actually took the approach of removing the processing from the UI thread and having it all execute in the threadpool which removed the issue around context. But how to fix it was not my question... the question, which Douglas answered, was what could be the cause as I was stumped. I added a note on the accepted answer to try to clarify this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen if you're blocking on that async method from a synchronization context that executes continuations on the original thread, such as a WPF or WinForms UI. Try adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` and check whether that avoids the hanging:

```
var readyTask = await Task.WhenAny(myLongRunningTask, Task.Delay(9000)).ConfigureAwait(false);
if (readyTask != myLongRunnnigTask && !myLongRunningTask.IsFaulted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("TimedOut");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

Comment: Interestingly I use this in 2 places. In the console app the task never hits the timeout and was working fine. It is in the winforms UI that it hangs... and trying the configure await false works :) I have no idea who downvoted this but it goes as my solution. thanks

Comment: There is a tendency for people to downvote what they perceive as "open-ended" questions and their answers. However, your question contained enough information for this issue to be identified. It's actually a very common issue in .NET when using async–await in WinForms or WPF applications. The root cause is that you're presumably calling `.Result` or `.Wait()` on the task returned from the async method containing the above code. See [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

> But I can't see what might side-effect it to this odd behaviour...

Your `longRunningTask` is likely assigned the return value of a method like:

```
private static Task NewMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(11000);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

then later:

```
var myLongRunningTask = NewMethod();
```

Thus, by the time you reach the `var readyTask = await` line, the 11 second sleep ('long running task') has **already occurred** (since `NewMethod` is not asynchonous), and thus `Task.WhenAny` returns instantly (since `longRunningTask` is complete).

Comment: In this case the task is not completed and not re-assigned. I made sure of that in one test case. Also the WhenAny does not return. That said it is an interesting point and I will revisit the activity of the task in other circumstances